# filters.Add vs FilterProviders.Providers.Add

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-filters

I came across a sample MVC3 code which had following in the `Global.asax` file:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(....)
{
    filters.Add(new MyFilter1());
    ....
    var provider = new MyFilterProvider();
    provider.Add(c => c.HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled ? new MyProvider2() : null);
    FilterProviders.Providers.Add(provider)
}
```

Both `MyProvider1` and `MyProvider2` are implemented with `IResultFilter`, and I am confused why one of them is added to `FilterProviders` and the other one is registered as a global filter.

Why and when should we add custom filters on `FilterProvider`, and why and when should we register them as global filters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you add a filter to `GlobalFilters.Filters` the filter will get executed for every request.

When you add an `IFilterProvider` to `FilterProviders.Providers` the filter provider will have a chance to decide whether a particular filter applies to the current request.

`FilterProviders` gives you greater control while `GlobalFilters` makes it easy to register a filter for the entire site.

Comment: Also I think a global filter is more static, it is created when registered. But filter provider can give you a chance to create a filter dynamically at run time.