# ASP.NET MVC: Register action filter without modifying controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I'm working with nopCommerce and I need to add in my only Action Filter, however, I don't want to modify the core controllers to avoid my code being overwritten when a new update is released.

I've setup my Action Filter:

```
public class ProductActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
        {
            ...
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

}
```

If I were to modify the controller, I could just add `[ProductActionFilter]` to the action I want it assigned to.

Is there a way I can register my custom Action Filter to a specific action without modifying the controller?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think global filters is what you need.

Once you created the filter register it in the global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start() {

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Register global filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
}
```

Add custom validation logic to filter if you want to apply it not to all actions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. A global filter does look like a suitable option and as you say, I could check for a specific controller/action. Just throwing something out there, rather than using `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add`, would `FilterProviders.Providers.Add` work the same? I'm not 100% sure how it works, but I've read it allows you to specify a certain controller/action...

Comment: @Scrooby Yes, FilterProvider may work too. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312624/filters-add-vs-filterproviders-providers-add.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your filter to be registered for every action (or it is otherwise OK to do so), then MVC 3 allows you to apply [Global action filters](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/01/15/configurable-global-action-filters-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx).  Of course this requires that nopCommerce is built on MVC 3, which I believe the newest version is?

Answer (score 2):

In NopCommerce 3.5 (the latest as of this answer, and newer than the question date), the best way I've found to add a global action filter is by creating a plugin with an `IStartupTask` implementation in it. This method completely avoids altering any NopCommerce core files.

The NopCommerce `Application_Start` event initializes the `EngineContext`, which creates the `NopEngine` instance. The `NopEngine` initialization finds all `IStartupTask` implementations, and executes them in their specified order. So an `IStartupTask` is the place to do anything that needs to happen on application start.

Sample code below:

```
public class Plugin : BasePlugin
{
    public Plugin()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check to see if this plugin is installed
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsInstalled(ITypeFinder typeFinder)
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> types = typeFinder.FindClassesOfType<IPluginFinder>(true);

        if (types.Count() == 1)
        {
            IPluginFinder plugins = Activator.CreateInstance(types.First()) as IPluginFinder;
            PluginDescriptor descriptor = plugins.GetPluginDescriptorBySystemName("MyPluginName");

            if (descriptor != null && descriptor.Installed)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Redirects to the 404 page if criteria not met
/// </summary>
public class FluffyTextureRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Kitten.Texture != Textures.Fluffy)
        {
            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
            routeValues.Add("controller", "Common");
            routeValues.Add("action", "PageNotFound");

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Does application start event stuff for the plugin, e.g. registering
/// global action filters
/// </summary>
public class StartupTask : IStartupTask
{
    private ITypeFinder _typeFinder;

    public StartupTask()
    {
        //IStartupTask objects are created via Activator.CreateInstance with a parameterless constructor call, so dependencies must be manually resolved.
        _typeFinder = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<ITypeFinder>();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        // only execute if plugin is installed
        if (Plugin.IsInstalled(_typeFinder))
        {
            // GlobalFilters is in System.Web.Mvc
            GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new FluffyTextureRequiredAttribute());
        }
    }

    public int Order
    {
        get { return int.MaxValue; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach works for NopCommerce 4.10

This code will redirect "/Register" requests with "GET" Method to "YourCustomAction" action inside "YourCustomController".

Step 1:
implement INopStartup

```
 public class NopStartup : INopStartup
 {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(config =>
            {
                config.Filters.Add<YourCustomActionFilter>();
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
        {

        }

        public int Order => 0;
    }
```

Step 2 :

```
public class YourCustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!(context.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)) return;

        if (actionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo == typeof(CustomerController) &&
            actionDescriptor.ActionName == "Register" &&
            context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "GET")
        {
                    string controllerName = nameof(YourCustomController).Replace("Controller", "");
                    string actionName = nameof(YourCustomController.YourCustomAction);
                    var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        action = actionName,
                        controller = controllerName
                    });
                    context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach, you can cut down the registration process and add some extra check/process then you can go on the registration process.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a partial class. As of version 2.60 all controllers are partials:

```
public partial class CatalogController : BaseNopController
```

You can put the filter to the class and then query the action name.